# How to I get python2.7 to be the default option when I call python on terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently installed the anaconda package while following a tutorial on data science from the guys at dataquest.io and after my install when I type "python" on the terminal I start Python 3 instead of 2.7.

How do I get "python" to open up python 2.7 again?

When I type

```
which python
```

and

```
which python3
```

I get the same path :

/Users/me/anaconda/bin/

**Using Mac OS X El Capitan**

Comment: The method changes depending on you're operation system.. but you shouldn't have an issue googling this and getting an answer.  Long story short change your PATH system environment to point to the correct python binary.

Comment: @reticentroot Being noobish everything seems harder than it is. :p
If I delete the entrance anaconda install made on my bash_profile, typing `python` opens 2.7, and if I type `which python` I get `usr/bin/Python` 

Is this what I add to the PATH?

Comment: Usr/bin/python looks like the default to me, so yeah that's your default if the path isn't that change it to that, however if you plan on using anaconda it may not work if it's pointed to your default and not anacondas version. I suggest you set up a virtual environment.. Google python virtualenv  to research what it is and how to set it up. It will keep your computer and python clean so issues like this don't happen

Comment: @JalxP What OS are you using?

Comment: @JalxP seems has been updated your default folder to python 3. So easy way is to remote anaconda file listed and download python 2.7.11 from anaconda. In case was anaconda and anaconda3 in your system than you can update the path (: export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH or export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH but in your case is just 1 folder ...)but now seems your system use anaconda what has been update after installation/upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with this some time ago and seem to remember that in my PATH variable in Windows (assuming Windows) - the PATH variable will be read such that the first python key is taken as the default.  So in Win 10, I pushed the one I want to the very top of the list and that worked for me.

Comment: They note that they are using OSX in the question

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, I'm running unix based system.

Comment: @JalxP Just say you are using Mac OS next time. Saying you are using a Unix-based OS is way too vague.

Comment: Yes, on the basis the OS wasn't specified when I answered, I would argue I didn't deserve the downvote.  It is true on Windows, incidentally, and so might be useful if a Windows user browses here.  @JalxP if you put MacOS in the title I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems has been updated your default anaconda and python folder to python 3.

Easy way is to remove `anaconda` folder listed and download python 2.7.11 from anaconda and reinstall.

In case you have anaconda and anaconda3 in your system than you can update the path according with your needs: export `PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH` or export `PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *soft link* from `python` to `python2.7,` namely:

```
$ pushd /bin && ln -s /bin/python python2.7

$ ls -ls `which python`
1 lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None 13 Feb 25  2016 /bin/python -> python2.7
```